# What is the name of Bastion's bird friend?

Tags: overwatch

During his default Heroic highlight intro you can see him play with a bird and his hero introduction screen shows him playing with a bird that rests on his shoulder.

Is there a name of his bird? Reminds me of Archimedes, the TF2 Medic's pet bird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of Bastion's bird is Ganymede. This is found in a PDF file of it mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/386fe7/til_bastions_bird_is_named_ganymede/) and shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOpTu.jpg). As mentioned by @Unionhawk, there is also a [highlight intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAudTILLq2s) of the same name featuring Bastion's bird. Also credit to @CloudyMusic, Bastion also has a [spray](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Bastion/Sprays?file=Bastion_Spray_-_Ganymede.png) that features his bird and has this name.

Comment: There is also a highlight intro of the same name that focuses on him

Comment: Ganymede also appears in a [Bastion spray bearing the same name](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Bastion/Sprays).

Comment: There's a player icon called Ganymede as well.  It's the bird.

Comment: There is now also a Ganymede plushie available in the Blizzard store, along the lines of the Pepe plushie from WoW :)