# What are Bastion's birds' names?

Tags: overwatch

I know that Bastion's main avian companion, who appears to be some variant of a goldfinch, [is named Ganymede](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266808/what-is-the-name-of-bastions-bird-friend). But what about the other birds? Each of Bastion's Epic and Legendary skins (aside from the Overgrown skin) show a different species of bird.

**Defense Matrix** has a Blue Jay.

**Omnic Crisis** has a Cardinal.

**Antique** and **Woodbot** have two different colors of a Woodpecker.

**Gearbot** has a Pigeon.

**Steambot** has a Dove.

Normally, I wouldn't expect such a minor character to have different names for each of the suits they wear, but Blizzard has been known to be quite a stickler for the smaller details.

Comment: I always thought the bird was Bastion, controlling a gigantic death robot.

Comment: I don't believe there are multiple names as the only name I've ever heard is Ganymede. But I haven't seen anything to confirm or deny it specifically.

Comment: That's basically where I'm at, but I figure I'm not the biggest lore buff, and maybe someone knows something I don't.

Comment: I searched a bit, and I have read all the lore I found, I never seen a mention of other names for ganymede. I don't think they did change the name for every skins, every caracters keep the same and Ganymede is probably having the same treatment .

Comment: Has anyone checked the highlight intro where Bastion tracks his bird? The highlight intro puts Ganymede's name on the screen, maybe it'll post a different name for the different species of birds?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266808/what-is-the-name-of-bastions-bird-friend

Comment: I'd say each variant is called Ganymede the same way as each Bastion is Bastion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't know**.

We can speculate all we want, but in reality there is no given name for any of those alternate birds.

Answer (score 7):

It can be assumed regardless of the bird's species, the name is still **Ganymede**.  I have tested out the "Ganymede" highlight intro with each of the different skins, and in each result, the text produced after scanning the bird is the same. Although it may be producing the result "Bird" in whatever the Omnic text might be, it seems to be identical throughout.

Comment: ...assuming that the text near the bird is in any way related to its name. Can't say I'm a fan of this answer.

Comment: +1, Bastion changes color when you switch skins, not crazy to think that Ganymede does as well

Comment: I think you can add the store as a source: http://gear.blizzard.com/overwatch/overwatch-ganymede-plush

Answer (score -2):

## Ganymede

That is the name of Bastions bird